# CMake submodules dependencies

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project with two submodules `A` and `B`. `B` depends on `A`. In submodule `B` I would like to search for `A` using `find_package(A CONFIG)`. My minimal (not) working example would be:

```
CMakeLists.txt
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
   project(AB)
   add_subdirectory(B)
   add_subdirectory(A)
A/CMakeLists.txt:
   message(STATUS "CMake: A")
   add_library(A SHARED A.hpp A.cpp)
   target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
   install(TARGETS A EXPORT AA LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/)
   export(TARGETS A NAMESPACE AA:: FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/A/AConfig.cmake)
   export(PACKAGE AA)
A/A.hpp (some non-sense code)
A/A.cpp
B/CMakeLists.txt
   find_package(A CONFIG)
   message(STATUS "---> ${A_FOUND}")
   add_library(B B.hpp B.cpp)
   target_link_libraries(B AA::A)
B/B.hpp (some non-sense code)
B/B.cpp
```

`A/CMakeList.txt` correctly produces a `AConfig.cmake`. But as I understand it does that after(!) `find_package(A CONFIG)` is called and therefore `AConfig.cmake` is not found.
Any idea how to force `find_package()` to run after `A` is executed?

Of course I know that in this example `find_package` does not make any sense. In my actual project the submodules are external software which I do not want to modify (in my case parallelSTL and TBB).

Comment: You need to **install** or, at least, **build** the project `A` before using `find_package(A)`. Because *building* is performed **after** the completing of *configuration* stage, when `CMakeLists.txt` scripts are processed, you cannot include both projects with `add_subdirectory` and expect things to work. For build project `A` **immediately** you may use `execute_process` command.

Comment: I am not totally got your meaning, Can you switch the order `add_subdirectory(B)` and  `add_subdirectory(A)`?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed cmake currently does not properly support this. A discussion for future plans can be found [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/17735). Here is my ugly workaround:

```
A/CMakeLists.txt:
   message(STATUS "CMake: A")
   add_library(A SHARED A.hpp A.cpp)
   target_include_directories(A PUBLIC "${CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
   install(TARGETS A EXPORT AA LIBRARY DESTINATION lib/)
   export(TARGETS A NAMESPACE AA:: FILE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/A/AConfig.cmake)
   export(PACKAGE AA)

   add_library(AA::A ALIAS A)
   file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/A/AConfig.cmake "")
   # include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
   # write_basic_package_version_file(
   #   ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/A/AConfigVersion.cmake
   #   VERSION 1.0.0
   #   COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion)
```

So the idea is to create a dummy file `AConfig.cmake`. This is overwritten later but it ensures that `find_package()` does not fail before it is actually created. Then we need to alias the target `A` to the name after the import `AA::A`. In case that there is a requirement on the version of `A`, than a file `AConfigVersion.cmake` needs to be created as well.
I created a MWE on [github](https://github.com/hansgans/cmake-subdirectory-dependencies).